# Change parameter 'param' type to 'java.lang.Object'

Tags: java, исключения, rest

Есть такой код

```
public static void call_me() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post");
        Map params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("name", "Jinu Jawad");
        params.put("email", "helloworld@gmail.com");
        params.put("CODE", 1111);
        params.put("message", "Hello Post Test success");
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
```

Map.Entry - компилятор пишет

Error:(29, 63) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Map.Entry

как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете на Java 5, то напишите так:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

если на Java 6 или выше, то так:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

если на Java 10 или выше, то можете даже так:

```
var params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

а оказывается нужно

```
Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
```

указывать дженерики явно. я думал это в прошлом)

Comment: В Java не обязательно указывать в правой части структуру создаваемой карты/коллекции. Достаточно `new LinkedHashMap<>()`. По крайней мере актуально для Java 7 и выше. А ваш пример является нормой для C#.

Comment: Тут дело не в том, что в прошлом или не в прошлом. Важен тип переменной, а не то, что вы ей присвоили. Тип переменной задается ее описанием. У вас `Map params` -- это равносильно `Map<Object, Object> params`.  Вы по сути сказали компилятору, что будете использовать свой `map` для объектов любого типа. Поэтому `params.entrySet()` будет возвращать набор `Map.Entry<Object, Object>` и компилятор не позволить присваивать это значение переменным более узкого типа. Если бы вы написали `Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();` (вы, наверное, это и имели в виду), проблемы бы не было.